# Two Foriegn Keys in Recursive Referenced Model

Tags: ef-core-2.2

UrlSet has a ShortnedUrl and ShortenedUrl can be part of a UrlSet

Not able to come up with a search query that finds me the expected recipe.

```
public class ShortenedUrl
{
    public string Raw { get; set; }
    public string Short { get; set; }
    public UrlSet Set { get; set; }
}
public class UrlSet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ShortenedUrl Short { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
}
```

at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one relationship between 'ShortenedUrl.Set' and 'UrlSet.Short'. To identify the child/dependent side of the relationship, configure the foreign key property. If these navigations should not be part of the same relationship configure them without specifying the inverse. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=724062 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I would still be very curious on how to do it the way i originally "brain farted" but in my case what I was doing was wrong, but I don't *think* that will always be the case...

Correct implementation:

```
public class ShortenedUrl
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Raw { get; set; }
    public string Short { get; set; }
}
public class UrlSet
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ShortenedUrl Short { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ShortenedUrl> Urls { get; set; }
}
```